# 'Take' or 'use' for elevator/ stairway?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Should I say,

> **Take** the elevator to floor number x

or

> **Use** the elevator to floor number x?

I want to know the same for stairways.

[This phrase is used in an app and to avoid the detection of *-st*, *-nd*, *-rd* and *-th*, I want to use only 'number x'.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In US usage,

> Use the elevator to floor number x?

would sound very strange. The same applies to similar sentences with *stairs* (*stairways* is not a common term in the US speech, except in technical materials).

The phrase *take the elevator (or stairs) to X ...* is the more common usage.

The phrase *use the elevator ...* would be found in circumstances not describing a specific location.

> *Use the elevator during business hours rather than the stairs.*
>
> *In case of fire, use the stairs.*

The verb **used** could be used to describe progress toward a specific location, but only with another verb, such as

> *Use the elevator **to exit** the building.*
>
> *Use the stairs **to access** the roof.*
>
> *Use the elevator **to get** to floor X*

Answer (score 2):

Both would be understood without hesitation, but *take* sounds more idiomatic, especially when the sentence mentions an explicit destination. I might prefer *use the elevator to go down* but I would use *take* in *take the elevator to the top floor*. (Disclaimer: I am not a native English speaker.)

*Take* wins the ngram fight for both [stairway](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+the+stairway%2Cuse+the+stairway&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20the%20stairway%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20the%20stairway%3B%2Cc0) and [elevator](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+the+elevator%2Cuse+the+elevator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20the%20elevator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20the%20elevator%3B%2Cc0).

“Floor number X” is less natural than “the Xth floor”, but it can be clearer to an international audience as it sidesteps the issue of first floor being the street floor or the floor above that. With “floor number X”, it's clear that you should look at the signs. If there are non-numbered floors (e.g. a basement floor), you can use an expression like “the floor marked B”.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say

> Use the elevator to floor 14.

You would have to say

> Use the elevator to go to floor 14,

because if you "*use* something *to*", the verb *use* needs a verb after *to*, and not a noun.